I'm using the python sounddevice libraries with persistent record stream overflows - how to solve?
Raspberry Pi 4 system.  The errors are occasional, every few seconds to minutes apart. They are evidenced by the Callback routine status being set and an error message generated.  I looked closely at the timing and discover that the callback is being called just as, or just after, the block of data is complete, i.e. if my block size is 50ms long, the callback happens within a millisecond of 50ms from the start of the buffer.  Looking at the wave data, there are a few incorrect samples amounting to ~150 microseconds of data.
I've tried changing microphone devices and tried changing the sampling rate, and the "latency" arguments for the stream.  These things did not seem to help.
The Callback is simple, putting the data in a buffer, collecting some time info, and setting and event so the processing task will deal with the data.
There are two other output streams running in my application and they have no difficulties.  the CPU resources used by the three steams is about 1.5% for each stream so total ~5% of the CPU.
So I'm looking for something that could be preventing a timely callback, or some way to prompt the callback to come a few microseconds earlier.
The structure of my program includes a threaded "mic_task" that starts the stream and handles the data from "rec_callback".
def rec_callback(indata, frames, time, status):
    global mic_AdcTime, mic_CurTime, lx
    if status:
        print('r:',status)
    
    idata[:] = indata                        # data passed via global 
                                             # numpy array idata

    mic_AdcTime = time.inputBufferAdcTime    # time instances only when 
                                             # getting active data
    mic_CurTime = time.currentTime     
  
    event_mic.set()
   
def mic_task():                      # background task always running!
    global mic_stream, mic_starttime, mic_sttime, buf, ii, io

    #sd.default.latency = 'high'
 
    if True:
        mic_stream = sd.InputStream(samplerate=rrate, device=micdev, 
            blocksize=block, channels=2, callback=rec_callback)
             
        mic_stream.start()
        mic_sttime = timer.time()       
        print('starting mic task')
    
        while True:
               
            event_mic.wait()    #the callback will release when there 
                                # is new data in buffer       
            if True:   
                qdata = idata.copy()                 
            
            etc...  process the data  

            event_mic.clear()  #go back to the wait until callback 
                               # releases again

Here is some sample output from the section of the base program that monitors the callback timings of the various streams:
>tm
sampling...  ^C to stop
my buffer underflow, ii: 1  io 1  going on...
**r: input overflow**
my buffer underflow, ii: 3  io 3  going on...
my buffer underflow, ii: 0  io 0  going on...

Averages for 147 samples
Callback to Buffer start time  Mean   Variance       Max       Min
mic input                    0.05009  0.00000001    0.05087     0.05000
playback out channel        -0.04136  0.00000911   -0.03942    -0.04991
chirp out channel           -0.06574  0.00000010   -0.06562    -0.06662

Block lengths are 50ms long ..
Suggestions about where to look would be appreciated.
